# merging in R keeping all rows of a data set

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames

distinct_paper_year_data:

```
author_id      distinct_paper_year_count
     1                         3
     2                         1
     4                         1
     5                         4
```

author_data:

```
author_id    paper_id  confirmed
   1         25733         1
   2         47276         1
   3         79468         1
   4         12856         0
```

Now I want to merge so that the desired output looks like:

```
author_id  paper_id     confirmed    distinct_paper_year_count
 1            25733          1               3
 2            47276          1               1 
 3            79468          1               0  
 4            12856          0               4
```

In this I need the `author_id`s present in the table `author_data` to be in the final output. Since there is no data for `author_id==3` in distinct_paper_year_count, the value of the `distinct_paper_year_count` column should be zero in the final result (for `author_id==3`).

By using merge I am getting

```
   merge(distinct_paper_year_data,author_data,by="author_id") 

author_id    distinct_paper_year_count paper_id confirmed
     1                         3       25733         1
     2                         1       47276         1
     4                         1       12856         0
```

How can the desired output be attained?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need an outer join:

```
merge(distinct_paper_year_data,author_data,by="author_id", all=T)
```

NB: You'll get `NA` for those rows where the tables don't match, like author_id in {3,5}. That said, you can simply modify the NAs if you need. You can also use `all.x` or `all.y` to do a left or right outer join.

Finally check out `data.table` for faster joins (and more functionality)

Comment: I need only the rows of author_data

Comment: @user3171906 ... ok. Then use `all.y = T`